# Is there a way to apply a filter when using a savedQuery in Dynamics CRM Web API?

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is there a way to apply a filter when using a savedQuery? 
For example, if a saved/pre-defined view returns multiple accounts, like with the following URL ".../api/data/v9.0/accounts?savedQuery=9e3ddee9-9e74-e811-a95d-000d3a34afa9", is there a way to return the results of the same saved view for a single account?

Comment: did you think to use plugin into SaveQuery Entity and apply your logic using this plugin?

Comment: it's for getting and updating the data through OData Web API to be used by an independent website.

Comment: I don't really understand the goal here. If you're running it for a single account why wouldn't you just use `api/data/v9.0/accounts({id of account})` to get that specific account - why do you need to run the view?

Comment: it's for more complex queries involving multiple entities. Using a pre-built view can be an alternative to building complex OData query.

Comment: Question is not understandable here. explain with scenario. Did you mean while using savedquery, you want to replace savedquery filter with other filter?

Comment: Here is a scenario. Let's say I built a view (save query) from accounts and link it to some custom entities like phones and addresses, adding filters to the joins... so it's somewhat of an involved query. Now that I have it working, I would like to filter it on one account. It seems at this point that it's impossible from the accounts, but can be done if I start building a view from one of the child entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a fetch XML to Web API. Simply download the fetch XML of the view through the Advanced Find. Here's an exemple in javascript:

```js
var accountFetchXML = ['< fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">' +
            '< entity name="account">' +
            '< attribute name="name" />' +
            '< filter type="and">' +
               '< condition attribute="industrycode" operator="not-null" />' +
            '</ filter>' +
            '< link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="primarycontactid" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="prmContact">' +
               '< attribute name="telephone3" />' +
               '< attribute name="description" />' +
             '</ link-entity>' +
           '</ entity>' +
         '</ fetch>'].join('');

var encodedFetchXML = encodeURIComponent(accountFetchXML);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts?fetchXml=" + encodedFetchXML, true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var accountDetails = results.value[i];

                //Single Line Text
                var nameValue = accountDetails['name'];
            }
        }
        else {
            alert(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```